# how to implement tab in the navigation title?

Tags: tabs, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I want to add tabs in the navigation title like below. Anyone could tell me the method to implement this.

I use swift2 and IOS9.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set any kind of `UIView` object to your `navigationItem` as a `titleView`

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

here `segmentedControl` maybe `UISegmentedControl` object.